# Sum range data in from specific range to previous month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to sum range only data from X month to previous month dynamically?

[image]

Problems in my case;
1. the sum function should start from the month where the person was joined +1, I mean if a person joined in feb then SUM starts from march and the range should stop in the current month -1, current month is august then range should be between March and Jul

I use this formula `SUM(H19:INDEX(F19:Q19,MONTH(TODAY())))` but it returns month as current month not the previous

Could you help me to achieve this goal??

Answer (score 0):

Sumifs should be able to handle this with some date manipulation.

```
=sumifs(3:3, 2:2, ">="&eomonth($c$19, 0)+1, 2:2, "<="&eomonth(today(), -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell `A19`:

  `=SUMIFS(A17:L17,A16:L16,">="&DATE(YEAR(A16),MONTH(A16)+1,DAY(A16)),A16:L16,"<="&DATE(YEAR(B21),MONTH(B21)-1,DAY(B21)))`

**N.B.**

- In sample data set `January` is start month & end month is `August`.
- Current month's date is in Cell `B21`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*